# Getting a table name from a variable in Oracle

Tags: oracle10g

Is it possible to store the name of the table as a variable in Oracle?  In other words, assume that I have two tables TXN-A and TXN-B in my database.  In my script, I have a variable called PRESENT_TABLE.

Depending upon the situation, I want this variable to refer to either TXN-A or TXN-B.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. Search for *native dynamic SQL* in Oracle PL/SQL.